# XSLT 2.0 node variable select by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

The XML File:

```
<XML>
    <Item ID = "test1"></Item>
    <Item ID = "test2"></Item>
</XML>
```

Result:

```
<XML>
    <Item ID = "TEST01"></Item>
    <Item ID = "TEST02"></Item>
</XML>
```

In my XSLT 2.0 file I want to acess the NewID of the variable if the currentID is equal to the OldID in order to change the attributes value with the predefined NewID.

```
<xsl:variable name="Items">
        <Item OldID="test1" NewID = "TEST01"></Item>
        <Item OldID="test2" NewID = "TEST02"></Item>
</xsl:variable>   

<xsl:template match="XML">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />         
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='ID']" />
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Items/Item[@OldID = @ID]/@NewID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete input, expected output, and your tried XSLT.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope now it's more clear.

Comment: Your updated code is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Items/Item[@OldID = current()/@ID]/@NewID"/>
```

--
P.S. Suggested reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key